# vb.net temporaraly disable external application

Tags: vb.net, disabled-control

I have a app which works with a program I have on my computer, this works well and is somthing that is well documented by the software developer.

The program (Autodesk inventor) allows for the user to use its own save dialoguebox as a trigger for launching, executing and the likes of whatever I like.

My question is as soon as my external app is launched  can we temporaraly disable the inventor interface till my app has compleated its task?

Comment: Can you please show a little bit of your code? So I can give you the require modification?

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example from my code, I hope you recognize it.

I just disable the screen updating and set silent operation ( no popup dialogs )

```
Public Class INV_APP
    Public oInvApp As Inventor.Application
    Public oInvStarted As Boolean = False

    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        Try
            oInvApp = Marshal.GetActiveObject("Inventor.Application")

        Catch ex As Exception
            Try
                Dim invAppType As Type = GetTypeFromProgID("Inventor.Application")

                oInvApp = CreateInstance(invAppType)
                oInvApp.Visible = True
                oInvStarted = True

            Catch ex2 As Exception

            End Try
        End Try

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button_click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        oInvApp.SilentOperation = True
        oInvApp.ScreenUpdating = False

        ' DO SOME COOL STUFF HERE.

        oInvApp.SilentOperation = False
        oInvApp.ScreenUpdating = True

    End Sub
    End Class
```